# C - While-Loop Duplicating Print Statements

Tags: c, while-loop, stdin, fgets

When the while-loop runs after the first time, it prints my "Create new node" prompt twice before getting user input from stdin. Why is this? See linked image.

Code:

```
int main()
{
  char userInput[2];
  while(1)
  {
    printf("\nCreate new node? (y/n)\n");
    printf(">>> ");
    fgets(userInput, 2, stdin);

    if(strcmp(userInput, "y") == 0)
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }

    else if(strcmp(userInput, "n") == 0)
    {
        printf("No\n");
        exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Terminal Output:

[image]

Comment: You are expected to post text as text, not images!

Comment: when calling`fgets()` should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the array: `userInput` is only two characters long.  so, using `fgets()` only one character at a time can be consumed from stdin.   This means if the user enters: `n<cr>` the `n` will be consumed  then on the next loop the `<cr>` will be consumed and code will loop again to get the users next actual input.  Suggest make the `userInput[]` several characters longer, say 2 or 3 characters longer.

Comment: the enable the user to enter `Y` or `N` insert a call to `tolower()` after the call to `fgets()` and before the first `if()`   Note: `tolower()` is prototyped in <ctype.h>

Comment: cont.  the tolower() function will want to handle (and return) a `int` rather than a `char`  so suggest using this line to input the value from the user: `while( (userInput = getchar()) == EOF ||  '\n' == userInput );`  And declare 'userInput' as: `int userInput;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` read string plus `'\0'` plus `'\n'`. Since `userInput` is of only `2` bytes, `'\n'` will not be read by `fgets` and will be there in the input buffer. On next iteration `fgets` will read `'\n'` left by the previous call of `fgets`.

Increase the buffer size and you will have no problem

```
char userInput[3];
```

or you can put

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

just after `fgets` statement.